# Calling a php file within a html file using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a PHP file that outputs my google analytics tracking code from my database. But unfortunately my website front end is HTML. Is there a way using Javascript to call my file templates/google-analytics-code.php and output my google tracking code?

This is my PHP file that outputs my tracking code:

```
<?php
include_once"../database.php";

$qry="select * from google_analytics";
$result=mysqli_query($con,$qry) or die(mysqli_error($con));

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $google_analytics_id = $row["google_analytics_id"]; 
    }
}

echo $google_analytics_id;
?>
```

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="google-site-verification" content="VFDwnGJ-4 
    RPz2jHchu3ARhbY2GLqkvyII4IbtAR-aP0" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.istreamradio.ie/css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.istreamradio.ie/css/font-awesome.css">
    <meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="80957862538-juiu2cgia32rn3lik36fv9a1ihc6fqof.apps.googleusercontent.com">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.istreamradio.ie/css/animate.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.istreamradio.ie/css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.istreamradio.ie/css/player.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <title>Listen Radio</title>
    <base href="/">
</head>

<body ng-app="musiclistener">
    <p><span ng-include="'templates/cookiebar-settings.php'"></span>
        <span ng-cloak>
        <span ng-view ></span>
        </span>
    </p>
    <div id='player-container'>
        <audio controls id='music-player' src="#"></audio>

        <div class='container-fluid'>
            <div class='col-sm-1 col-xs-3 text-center' id='play-icon-container'>
                <i class='fa fa-play' id='play-btn' ng-click="playtoogle()">
        </i>
            </div>
            <div class='col-sm-1 center-block hidden-xs' id='podcast-icon-container'>
                <img src="{{ playerthumb }}" id='play-img' class='img-responsive center-block'>
            </div>
            <div class='col-md-6 col-sm-4 col-xs-6' id='podcast-bar-container'>
                <span style='color:#fff;position:relative;top:3px;text-transform:capitalize' ng-if="musicplayingentity">{{ musicplayingentity}}</span>
                <div id='podcast-progress'>
                    <div id='podcast-id-value'></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class='col-md-1 col-sm-2 text-center hidden-xs' id='addons-icon-container'>

                <span ng-hide="userLoggedIn">
                    <a href data-toggle="modal" data-target="#loginModal"><i 
    class='fa fa-plus pull-left'></i></a>           
                    <a href data-toggle="modal" data-target="#loginModal"><i 
    class='fa fa-comment '></i></a>
                </span>

                <span ng-show="userLoggedIn">
                    <i ng-click="makeFavoritePlayer()" ng-hide="playingfav" class='fa fa-plus extrafun'></i>
                    <i ng-click="removeFavoritePlayer()" ng-show="playingfav" class='fa fa-check extrafun'></i>
                    <i ng-click="showCommentBoxPlayer()" class='fa fa-comment '></i>
                </span>

                <i class='fa fa-share pull-right' ng-click="shareboxPlayer()"></i>
            </div>
            <div class='col-sm-3 col-xs-3 text-center' id='volume-container'>
                <div class='col-xs-2'>
                    <i class='fa fa-volume-up'></i>
                </div>
                <div class='col-xs-1 col-md-9'>
                    <div id='volume-progress'>
                        <div id='volume-id-value'></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
    <script src="http://www.istreamradio.ie/ang/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://www.istreamradio.ie/ang/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://www.istreamradio.ie/ang/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://www.istreamradio.ie/ang/angular-cookies.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://www.istreamradio.ie/ang/angular-facebook-sdk.js"></script>
    <script>
        window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
            FB.init({ appId: '195962897544265', xfbml: true, version: 'v2.8' });
        };
    </script>
    <script src="http://www.istreamradio.ie/ang/app.js"></script>
    <script src="http://www.istreamradio.ie/ang/controllers.js"></script>
    <script src='http://www.istreamradio.ie/js/jquery.js'></script>
    <script src='http://www.istreamradio.ie/js/bootstrap.js'></script>
    <script src='http://www.istreamradio.ie/js/typed.js'></script>
    <script src='http://www.istreamradio.ie/js/wow.js'></script>
    <script src='http://www.istreamradio.ie/js/player.js'></script>
    <script>
        new WOW().init();
    </script>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $(".typing-text").typed({
                strings: ["MUSIC", "SPORTS", "BOOKS", "NEWS", "TALK"],
                typeSpeed: 200,
                backSpeed: 150,
                loop: true
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: My answer shows you how to 'Call a php file within an html file using JavaScript', as this post is titled, and as you explain what you are trying to do.  However, for your purposes, there's no reason to fire up all that code on each page visit (+it will not work as intended without further modifications).  You can simply insert your google analytics tracking code in your html file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with AJAX.

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: 'templates/google-analytics-code.php',  // make sure to give this a valid path
    success: function(data){
        // the data returned is passed to the success function.  You can do anything with it in here, like appending it to the DOM with jQuery.
        $('body').append(data);
    }
});
</script>
```

Note:  You will need to have jQuery loaded for this.

Comment: Thanks, I have tried using this method. but all it does is gives me a popup. I need to append the output in somewhere within the body tags.

Comment: Congrats, It is working!  The reason it gives you a popup with the information is because of this line:  `alert(data);`.  Exchange that with code that will append the variable `data` to the body, like `$( "body" ).append(data);`.

Comment: Can you give me an example of what you mean thanks a million.

Comment: Ok, I updated the code to append the output to the body within a `div`.

Comment: Cheers man, But it is displaying the tracking code on the index page as in the front end. Have a look yourself www.istreamradio.ie

Comment: Also when I look at page source I cant see the tracking code

Comment: I have no clue what your index.html file looks like, but I knew it definitely has a body...  Use the appropriate jQuery selector to append the data where you want it to appear.

Comment: Page source shows you the original source code without anything that was added later on with JS.  However, the inspector will show it.

Comment: I have amended an added my index page in above.

Comment: There's actually no reason to make an ajax call and a database call each time a user visits your page to get the same data.  Just take that output, and put it directly into your html file.

Answer (score 1):

The php would have to exist on a web server and be capable of listening for some kind of request (http most likely) containing GET or POST data, and respond accordingly. You can't just do it with the file system.

One option is to make your file index.php instead of index.html and echo out the html you wanted.

Comment: I cant make the index.php as all the other front end files are html.